# jQuery Sortable prevent user to move child item to parent item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have this list in HTML:

```
<ol class="sortable subcategory_item">
    <li data-id="102">A</li>
    <li data-id="111">B</li>
    <li data-id="1712">GROUP A
        <ol class="group_items">
            <li data-id="105">GROUP MEMBER 1</li>
            <li data-id="108">GROUP MEMBER 2</li>
            <li data-id="109">GROUP MEMBER 3</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li data-id="110">C</li>
    <li data-id="113">D</li>
</ol>
```

The problem is I am able to move items under `GROUP A` to their parent.

How can I prevent `GROUP MEMBER 1`, `GROUP MEMBER 2` and `GROUP MEMBER 3` (or items inside `<ol class="group_items">` to be moved above `GROUP A`?

I am currently using [jquery-sortable plugin](https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/) but I am okay if I have to switch using another plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use jQuery UI sortable which behaves the way you want by default:

```js
$('.sortable,.group_items').sortable();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ol class="sortable subcategory_item">
  <li data-id="102">A</li>
  <li data-id="111">B</li>
  <li data-id="1712">GROUP A
    <ol class="group_items">
      <li data-id="105">GROUP MEMBER 1</li>
      <li data-id="108">GROUP MEMBER 2</li>
      <li data-id="109">GROUP MEMBER 3</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li data-id="110">C</li>
  <li data-id="113">D</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Accepted as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the demo

```js
$("#sortable").sortable({
  change: function(event, ui) {
    var currentClass = $(ui.placeholder)[0].classList[0];
    if (!$(ui.placeholder).prev().hasClass(currentClass) && !$(ui.placeholder).next().hasClass(currentClass))
      return false;
  }
});
$(".group_items").sortable();

$("#sortable").disableSelection();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-sortable/0.9.13/jquery-sortable-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ol class="sortable subcategory_item" id="sortable">
  <li data-id="102" class="grp1">A</li>
  <li data-id="111" class="grp1">B</li>
  <li data-id="1712" class="grp1">GROUP A
    <ol class="group_items">
      <li data-id="105" class="grp">GROUP MEMBER 1</li>
      <li data-id="108" class="grp">GROUP MEMBER 2</li>
      <li data-id="109" class="grp">GROUP MEMBER 3</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li data-id="110" class="grp1">C</li>
  <li data-id="113" class="grp1">D</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks!